# How to process an URL and retrive segments in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm building a site with URLs in SEO friendly pattern, like

`http://yourdomain.com/category/subcategory/finalcategory/topic_identifier/` etc,

here the last value topic_identifier is the one with which I look into database, unique string just replacement of unique IDs, I want to see the hierarchical values though, and I may get some pagination values too like

`/topic_identifier/p/2/a/3/f/5/`

here I need to get p,a,f values too from the same URL.
Can some one help me out of this logic?

Comment: Something like `preg_match('/p\/(\d+)/', $url, $p); echo $p[1]`?

Comment: @putvande Thanks for that, we can get those p,a,f values using preg_match or some other php function, but you cant get the exact location of topic_identifier, I need to get this into a variable so i can lookup into DB with it then.

Comment: ...Or you could simply use a framework like Laravel which handles this as routes.

Comment: You said to need help with the logic getting p, a and f out of the url.

Answer (score -1):

Check the following code. It may help you

```
$url = 'http://yourdomain.com/category/subcategory/finalcategory/
topic_identifier/p/2/a/3/f/5/';

preg_match('/p\/\d+\/a\/\d+\/f\/\d+/', $url, $p);
$str = implode('/',$p);

$array = explode('/',$str);

echo 'p=>'.$array[1]."<br/>";
echo 'a=>'.$array[3]."<br/>";
echo 'f=>'.$array[5]."<br/>";
```

Comment: Why does the last `d` in your preg_match have a `+` and all the others not?

Comment: d check for digits in the url

Comment: Yes I know. But your regular expression only checks for multiple digits at the end of the url. So for example `/p/11/a/1/f/1` would fail.